# Find the n that is a positive integer makes the equation have a positive integer solution, if it has no solution, please prove it.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

$$\begin{cases}\frac{x}{6n}\in N\\
\frac{81n^5-n}{8x}\in N\end{cases}，\frac{x}{6n}<\frac{81n^5-n}{8x}，x,n∈N$$
I try to let $x=6nk$ ,then $\frac{81n^5-n}{8x}=\frac{81n^4-1}{48k}$,and
I think I can try to solve$\frac{81n^4-1}{48}∈N$ first, but I don't know what should I do next.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: Hint: try denote integer quantities as $k$ and $l$ and compose equation for $n$ in terms of $k$ and $l$.

Answer (score 0):

There must exist $R,S \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ such that

- $x = 6nR$
- $81n^5 - n = 8xS = 8(6nR)S$
- $R < S$.

However, since you are given that $n$ must be a positive integer, you can assume that $n \neq 0.$  Therefore, you can divide the 2nd constraint above by $n$.

This implies that

$$81n^4 - 1 = 48RS. \tag1 $$

However, (1) above is impossible to satisfy, because the LHS is congruent to $-1 \pmod{3}$ and the RHS is congruent to $0 \pmod{3}.$

Answer (score 0):

first, $81n^4-1$ can be written as $(3n-1)(3n+1)(9n^2+1)$ , and obviously,
three of them are not divisible by $3$, so $\frac{81n^4-1}{48}$ won't be a positive
integer.From the above, you can know for all k is a positive integer, $\frac{81n^4-1}{48k}$ won't be a positive integer, and no doubt, $\frac{x}{6n}$ won't be a positive
integer too.